# Spring Roo plugin directory

Tags: spring-roo

Is there a public directory of Spring Roo plugins available?

I know only this forum thread [Spring Roo Community AddOns](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101800-Spring-Roo-Community-Add-Ons), but I know that there are a lot of others plugins available, anyway I did not find a page which lists them all. Grails for example has its own [Plugin portal](http://grails.org/plugins/).

What I do is search Google code for [roo addon](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/query/#q=roo%20addon) and [roo plugin](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/query/#q=roo%20plugin), but I am not satisfied with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far, one of the best lists I have seen is the one on Wikipedia article on Spring Roo.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Roo

However, you should be able to list all available Spring Roo addons/plugins by executing the following command at your Roo Console. Please note you might need an internet connection for this command to work successfully.

```
addon list
```

For more information, please refer the topic Spring Roo Addons under the Spring Roo Documentation.

Cheers!